Lug nut won’t come off, edges ground down
Was trying to remove lug nut on BMW, the edges of it got ground down so any wrench I use won’t turn it properly. Need to change tires at some point, so is there anything I can do to remove it?


Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I can ask, what were you using to loosen the lug nut? Are you sure what you were using was fully engaging the hex? It looks like (what little I can see of it) that the outer tip of the lug is what is getting engaged, and not much below that. Wondering if something deeper might be able to engage it better.

Google is your friend. This link uses a jackstand to hold the extension for a better way to avoid damage to wheel finish; https://youtu.be/gdjSSXhyoJk. Here's another link; https://youtu.be/M7TX2lxgi10

If you don't get advice here that gives you enough confidence to get the lug nut off by yourself, I suggest you take the car to a tire shop. Lug nuts are key to their business, they deal with lug nuts all day long, and they have all the tools and expertise to get the job done quickly and efficiently.

BMW uses lug bolts, not lug nuts, on their vehicles, and this is a lug bolt shown in the picture. That said, make sure you are using the correct size socket, it should be 17mm on most BMW models. This looks slightly rounded, but not so bad that it should not come out with the correct tool. If it is, one could use special sockets designed to remove stripped bolts and nuts, such as RBRT sockets. However, before you get too far into this, if you are not experienced at removing stuck bolts, I would recommend going to a shop to get this addressed. It's easy to damage your wheel if you are not careful, and swapping wheels or tires at a shop will be cheaper than buying a new wheel.
